# How to handle this routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I have URL's like:

- /nl/blog (shows overview of blog items)
- /nl/blog/loont-lekker-koken-en-wordt-eerlijkheid-beloond (shows blog item with urltitle)
- /nl/blog/waarom-liever-diëtist-dan-kok (shows blog item with urltitle)

for which I have defined routes:

- A: route "nl/blog/{articlepage}" with constraint articlepage = @"\d"
- B: route "nl/blog"
- C: route "nl/blog/{urltitle}/{commentpage}" with constraint commentpage = @"\d"
- D: route "nl/blog/{urltitle}"

Question 1: this works fine, but maybe there's a better solution with less routes?

Question 2: to add a new article, I have an action method AddArticle in BlogController. Of course, with the routes defined above, the url "/nl/blog/addarticle" would map to route D, where addarticle would be the urltitle which is not correct of course. Therefore I added the following route:

- E: route "nl/blog/_{action}"

and so now the url "/nl/blog/_addarticle" maps to this route, and execute the correct action method. But I was wondering whether there is a better way to handle this?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Nice question. I'm really interested in any answers.

Comment: Maybe custom route constraint could be the most elegant solution?

Comment: ok, for question 2 I found the answer myself. I created a custom constraint called ExcludeConstraint, and changed route D as: route "nl/blog/{urltitle}" with constraint "new { urltitle = new ExcludeConstraint(new List<string>() { "addarticle", "addcomment", "gettags"}) }));". Now, my url stays clean, like /nl/blog/addcomment

Comment: The only change you can do with these routes and your requirements is to combine routes C and D, and add a `UrlParameter.Optional` declaration for commentPage.

Comment: thanks counsellorben, that's indeed part of the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers to my own questions:

For question one, I created a custom constraint IsOptionalOrMatchesRegEx:

```
public class IsOptionalOrMatchesRegEx : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string _regEx;

    public IsOptionalOrMatchesRegEx(string regEx)
    {
        _regEx = regEx;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var valueToCompare = values[parameterName].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueToCompare)) return true;
        return Regex.IsMatch(valueToCompare, _regEx);
    }
}
```

Then, routes A and B can be expressed in one route:

- url: "nl/blog/{articlepage}"
- defaultvalues: new { articlepage = UrlParameter.Optional }
- constraints: new { articlepage = new IsOptionalOrMatchesRegEx(@"\d")

For question 2, I created an ExcludeConstraint:

```
public class ExcludeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly List<string> _excludedList;

    public ExcludeConstraint(List<string> excludedList)
    {
        _excludedList = excludedList;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var valueToCompare = (string)values[parameterName];
        return !_excludedList.Contains(valueToCompare);            
    }
}
```

Route D could then be changed like:

- url: "nl/blog/{urltitle}"
- constraints: new { urltitle = new ExcludeConstraint(new List() { "addarticle", "addcomment", "gettags"}) }));